# Why does the Strange Quark have Strangeness -1?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, definition, conventions, quarks

I have been trying to find an explanation for the strange quarks negative strangeness value, I understand the term [strangeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness) predates the quark model, but I'm unsure if terminology carry over is the reason for the naming convention.

Apparently, it is also convention to give quantum numbers a positive or negative value depending on the charge of the particle. Does the strange quark's negative charge give it a negative strangeness?

Comment: to keep with the convention used when the kaon was discovered , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon  at the quark level

Comment: For the same reason electrons are negatively charged: [we guessed wrong which convention would be most useful](https://xkcd.com/567).

Comment: If either of you would like to write your comments up into a full answer I'd happily accept one of them.

Comment: A strange quark with strangeness +1 would be just what you'd expect, and therefore not strange at all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article [Strangeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Strangeness&oldid=1077689384):

> The terms *strange* and *strangeness* predate the discovery of the quark,
> and were adopted after its discovery in order to preserve the
> continuity of the phrase; strangeness of anti-particles being referred
> to as +1, and particles as −1 as per the original definition. For all
> the quark flavour quantum numbers (strangeness, charm, topness and
> bottomness) the convention is that the flavour charge and the electric
> charge of a quark have the same sign. With this, any flavour carried
> by a charged meson has the same sign as its charge.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I read that; I didn't find the paragraph definitive, why was +1, -1 the original definition?

Comment: @Connor This is the very point of the paragraph: The strangeness of the $K^-$ was assigned to be -1, same as its charge. The charm of the $D^+$ is assigned to be +1, same as its charge.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ahh, okay, that isn't clear to me from the paragraph! Probably because I don't know the history, but thank you!

Comment: It's all about memorable conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of additive quantum numbers is set up to a convention. Take for example the case of the electric current: we use to say in electronics that current is a positive flow of charge, that is a negative flow in the opposite direction.

Having this in mind, a subnuclear physics reason can be that the Gell-Mann & Nishijima formula that relates electric charge $Q$, strong isospin $I_3$, barionic number $B$ and strangeness $S$ (the sum of these two and all other quark numbers is called strong hypercharge, $Y$) states:
$$ Q = \frac{B+S}{2} + I_3 $$
Because of this, reminding that the charge of quark strange is $-\frac{1}{3}$ we obtain the correct solution if we put $I_3 = 0$, $B = \frac{1}{3}$ and $S = -1$.